# Convert GMT time to Local time in python

Tags: python, datetime

I have a date(datetime) which is stored in the database as GMT time.
I need to convert this to local time.How can i achieve this using python

Please have your suggestions

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Are you using Python 2.x or Python 3.x?  The answer is mostly the same, but the details differ.

Comment: Many thanks for your support..Sorry for the delay in reply..im using python 2.7

Answer (score 2):

Have you read the Python documentation, [8.1 *`datetime` — Basic date and time types*](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html)
and especially [8.3 *`tzinfo` objects*](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html#tzinfo-objects)?

They describe the library function [`datetime.astimezone(`*tz=None*`)`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone), which may be exactly what you want.

> Return a datetime object with new tzinfo attribute tz, adjusting the date and time data so the result is the same UTC time as self, but in tz‘s local time.

They have example code there for defining a time zone in terms of an offset from UTC, ending with a declaration like:

```
Pacific  = USTimeZone(-8, "Pacific",  "PST", "PDT")
```

Having read that, what is your question?

Do you have a `date` or a `datetime`?  i.e. does the data have a time zone component? If no time component, then what is the meaning of changing the date to a different time zone?

Do you have a 'naive' or 'aware' `datetime`? From the docs,

> An aware object has sufficient knowledge of applicable algorithmic and political time adjustments, such as time zone and daylight saving time information, to locate itself relative to other aware objects. An aware object is used to represent a specific moment in time that is not open to interpretation....
>
> A naive object does not contain enough information to unambiguously locate itself relative to other date/time objects. Whether a naive object represents Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), local time, or time in some other timezone is purely up to the program, just like it is up to the program whether a particular number represents metres, miles, or mass. Naive objects are easy to understand and to work with, at the cost of ignoring some aspects of reality.

The Python documentation is really quite good. Perhaps it will answer your questions without you having to ask StackOverflow.